# lxml - UnicodeDecodeError when accessing text of an element

Tags: python, html, unicode, utf-8, lxml

I am working with some Python code that uses the `lxml HTML` parser to parse the HTML that a co-worker scraped from a random sample of web sites.

In two of them, I get an error of the form

> "'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe20x80 in position 502: unexpected
>   end of data",

and the HTML content does contain a corrupt `UTF-8` character.

A variable in the code called ele is assigned to a <p> element surrounding the text with the bad character, and that text can be accessed via ele.text. Or it could be, but merely assigning ele.text to another variable causes the `UnicodeDecodeError` to be raised. The object of type `UnicodeDecodeError` that is available in the except clause contains some useful attributes such as the start and end positions of the bad bytes in the text, which could be used to create a new string from which the bad bytes have been removed, but doing anything to ele.text, such as taking a substring of it, causes a new `UnicodeDetectError` to be raised. Is there anything I can do to salvage the good parts of `ele.text`?

I am writing this from memory, and I don't remember all the details of the code, so I can supply more information tomorrow if it's useful. What I remember is that ele is an object of a type something like `lxml._Element`, the file being parsed really is in `utf-8`, and there is a place in the file where the first two `utf-8` bytes of the the character that matches the entity &rdquo; is followed by the entity &rdquo;. So the text contains `"xE2x80&amp;rdquo;"`. The error message complains about the `"xE2x80"` and gives their position in a string that has about 520 characters in it. I could discard the whole string if necessary, but I'd rather just use the position info to discard the `"xE2x80"`. For some reason, doing anything with ele.text causes an error in lower level Cython code in lxml. I can provide the stack trace tomorrow when I am at work. What, if anything can I do with that text? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`e2 80` bytes by themselves do not cause the error:

```
from lxml import html

html_data = b"<p>before &ldquo;\xe2\x80&rdquo; after"
p = html.fromstring(html_data)
print(repr(p.text))
# -> u'before \u201c\xe2\x80\u201d after'
```

As @Esailija pointed out in the comments the above doesn't interpret the data as utf-8. To force utf-8 encoding:

```
from lxml import html

html_data = b"""<meta http-equiv="content-type"
                      content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                <p>before &ldquo;\xe2\x80&rdquo; after"""
doc = html.fromstring(html_data.decode('utf-8','ignore'))
print(repr(doc.find('.//p').text))
# -> u'before \u201c\u201d after'
```

- check that utf-8 is the correct character encoding for the document
- replace the broken byte sequence before passing it to lxml

Comment: Yes they do, `e2` is a lead byte for 3 byte long UTF-8 sequence. You can cause it just by writing `"\xe2\x80".decode("utf-8")`

Comment: @Esailija: what do you get if you run the code from the answer?

Comment: There is no decoding attempt (as utf-8) in your answer at all

Comment: @Esailija: try `type(p.text)`. What do you see?

Comment: I see the result of effective `"\xe2\x80".decode("iso-8859-1")`

Comment: @Esailija: you are right. I've added variant that forces utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Is there a fast way to detect and replace the bad bytes before parsing the text? Would calling `decode("utf-8")` on the whole string work? Or should I try to parse the HTML, detect the error, remove the bad bytes and parse the HTML again?

Comment: @Michael: you could specify 'ignore' option to ignore decoding errors